# How to bind WinForms' DataGridView to EF navigation property (collection) in master-detail scenario?

Tags: winforms, data-binding, datagridview, entity-framework-6, bindingsource

I have a databinding problem in Windows Forms.

Here's the part of the EF model that is relevant for the story:

```
namespace Model
{
    class Person 
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public String Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Receipt> Receipts { get; set; }
    }

    class Receipt 
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
        public double Value { get; set; }

        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    }
}
```

There is a BindingSource called `peopleBindingSource` that is set to class `Model.Person`. In code behind, I do this:

```
db.People.Include(p => p.Receipts).Load();
peopleBindingSource.DataSource = db.People.Local.ToBindingList();
```

Textbox has its DataBindings set to `peopleBindingSource` as DataSource and `Name` as the property.

When I run the application, the binding navigator works correctly, showing different people as I click previous and next buttons. The textbox with the person's name is also populated correctly.

Now, here comes the problem:

On the same form, there is a DataGridView. I want to **show a row** for each of the Receipt of **currently selected** Person.

I've tried to bind `dataGridView's DataSource` to `Receipts` navigation property of `peopleBindingSource`.

I have expected that the gridview will update its DataSource to the appropriate collection of receipts just as the textbox updates its Text property on navigation change. The setup is basicly the same.

The thing is, no error is thrown, and the **grid remains empty** (it doesn't even create the columns header).

Why doesn't this binding work and can this be done from within the designer? How to correctly set up binding (without programatically handling change event on peopleBindingSource and setting grid's DataSource manually from peopleBindingSource.Current)?

Comment: can you post the code where you bind the datasource to your datagridview?

Comment: I can't because I didn't bind it in code, but in designer. However, I have found what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to the problem.

The thing is that `DataGridView` can't bind to `ICollection<Receipt>` so the solution was to change the navigation property to `BindingList<Receipt>`. Then the designer showed the property correctly.

Comment: I have the same problem, how do you change that think ?